# How to add/remove a group of fields using jQuery in a multi-step Rails 3 form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a Rails 3 app with a multi-step form that I developed using this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

In the 3rd step(not the last step) of my form, I have a group of fields, called "Audience", which contains 4 select boxes.

Using Jquery, I have "add" and "remove" links next to this group of fields, so that I can have multiple "Audiences" in the form.

So for example, I start off with 1 Audience. If I click "add", then I have another Audience for a total of 2 Audiences (2 groups of fields). However, if I click on "remove", then that Audience will be removed from the form, and I'll be left with 1 Audience (1 group of fields) again.

This Audience form is nested. I used the nested form gem for this: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/

My problem is that no matter what I try, this Audience portion of the form never seems to work correctly. Right now, when the Audience form page first loads, the "remove" link doesn't appear at all, and every time I click the "add" link, 2 groups of fields are added instead of just 1. When I go to another page, and then come back to the Audience form again, then the "remove" link reappears, but the "add" link still does the same thing. Every time I go back to the page, more fields are added without me even clicking on the "add" link. In addition, I set a limit to the number of fields, but that doesn't work either.

I've spent the better part of a week on this problem, and I still can't figure it out. My Jquery skills are not wonderful, but I can do the basics. I've repeatedly asked for suggestions, but they never work. I'm desperate at this point...I already started banging my head against the wall a few days ago.

I have a good demonstration of what I want here, just replace "beets" with a group of fields: http://jsfiddle.net/beehive/8zJr6/

Any suggestions for a solution to this would be greatly appreciated. Maybe I should just go with a different approach entirely?

**application.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Nested Audience form
    var x = $('#audiencefields');
    var i = $('#audiencefields p').size() + 1;

    $('#addlink').live('click', function() {
        if ($(".item", x).length < 3) {
            $('<p class="item" id="audiencecontainer">beets '+ i +'#removelink').appendTo(i);
            i++;
        }
        return false;
    });

    $('#removelink').live('click', function() {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });


});
```

**_audience_step.html.erb**

```
<div class="uploadcontent">
    <h1 class="uploadtitle">select your audience</h1>
    <div id="audiencefields">
        <p id="audiencecontainer">
            <%= f.fields_for :audiences do |audience_form| %>
                <ul class="uploadformlist">
                  <li>  
                    <%= audience_form.label :number_of_people, "Size" %><br />
                    <%= audience_form.collection_select :number_of_people, Audience::PEOPLE, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= audience_form.label :gender %><br />
                    <%= audience_form.collection_select :gender, Audience::GENDERS, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= audience_form.label :age %><br />
                    <%= audience_form.collection_select :age, Audience::AGES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <%= audience_form.label :ethnicity %><br />
                    <%= audience_form.collection_select :ethnicity, Audience::ETHNICITIES, :to_s, :to_s, :include_blank => true %>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <%= audience_form.link_to_remove "Remove this audience", :id => "removelink" %>
           <% end %>
        </p>
   </div>
   <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add another audience", :audiences, :id => "addlink" %></p>

</div>
```

**audience.rb**

```
class Audience < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :ethnicity, :gender, :number_of_people

  belongs_to :upload

  #validates_presence_of :age, :ethnicity, :gender, :number_of_people

  PEOPLE = ['5', '10', '25', '50', '75', '100']
  GENDERS = ['Male', 'Female']
  ETHNICITIES = ['Caucasian/White', 'African-American/Black', 'Latin/Hispanic', 'Asian', 'Indian', 'Middle-Eastern', 'Native American']
  AGES = ['0-2', '3-5', '6-12', '13-17', '18-29', '30-39', '40-49', '50-59', '60+']
end
```